# Converting GML to GeoJSON - offset is out of bounds

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, gml

I need to convert a GML file to GeoJSON from this website (https://use-land-property-data.service.gov.uk/datasets/inspire/download) and store it in my MongoDB database.

I have read a few posts on here and managed to install Conda on my windows machine and then in the conda prompt went to the input.gml directory and used

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.gml`

Now when uploading the output.geojson into my db, I get the console error: "offset is out of bounds". Does anyone know why this is?

Code for my LRCP schema:

```
const featureSchema = new Schema({
    properties: Object,
    geometry: Object
});

const lrcpSchema = new Schema({
  councilName: {
    type: String,
    unique: true, // Ensure each council has a unique name
    required: true,
  },
  features: [featureSchema],
});
```

Comment: Can you add a sample point in each format?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you should use layer creation option `-lco RFC7946=YES` that converts data into WGS84 lon-lat coordinates https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#layer-creation-options.

Comment: Here is the start of the .geojson file: "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 340410.049999999988358, 399791.700000000011642 ], [ 340418.650000000023283, 399785.349999999976717 ]

and for the gml:
<LR:GEOMETRY><gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2" gml:id="PREDEFINED.fid--7a61a0dc_18c2dff496b_-b84.GEOMETRY"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>340410.05 399791.7 340418.65 399785.35

So the points are rounded up, and dont look skewed..

Answer (score 1):

The `-lco RFC7946=YES` command was correct for transforming the GML data to GeoJSON correctly.

Also I was trying to store over 100k documents in one sub-collection which I think was causing an error